# Message Box body display in Landscape mode in multiple lines

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, messagebox

I have message box that is displayed with different messages on different scenarios. My problem is that in portrait mode the message body is fine but in landscape even though there is a lot of space the message body gets wrapped and gets displayed in multiple lines. Why not spread the message text completely??? Is this a known issue in WP7 or is it the native behaviour? To make you all understand the problem am talking about, am attaching 2 pictures of message boxes in Landscape and portrait mode. I have taken a message box with really lengthy message text for testing.

Here is the code for the message box:

```
void btnLike_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        msgPrompt.Hide();
        MessageBoxResult result = new MessageBoxResult();
        result=MessageBox.Show("Thank You for your feedback!! It was nice to know that you liked this app, We will be back with a more amazing features!!! Upgrades will be available soon!!!", "Feedback", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Please do have a look and provide your comments or fixes in form of code (If any).

Thank you,
Apoorva :)[image: Portrait Mode]
[image: Landscape mode with text aligned just the same as in portrait mode]

Comment: And what does the source for the message look like?

Comment: I will edit my question and post the code that am using to display the message box. Actually its a simple message box...Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: OK, this seems indeed to be 'by design'. I don't think the msgbox will shrink when you use a (much) shorter text.

Comment: I have feedback--LESS EXCLAMATION POINTS!!!!!!

Comment: @Will I know I know.. That was coz i wanted to make the message really big !! :)

Comment: You can make use of custom dialogs for this purpose. than relaying on the MessageBox. :)

Comment: @Santhu can u give example. Coz i need to use message box with different types of buttons. So will that be possible to achieve?

Comment: You can refer this link http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this might be the standard behavior (it looks like it is), you can quite simply create your own custom control to achieve what you'd like to do. I made my first one the other day, and it was quite easy really.

For more information about how to do the same, you can look at some of these links:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/7-Mistakes-Developer-make-when-implementing-Windows-Phone-Custom-Controls

Happy coding :-)